# Updating z value of geometry using updateCursor?

Tags: arcpy, polygon, cursor, update

I am trying to update the Z value of a polygon using update Cursor and it just doesn't work!

I have been exploring this site and trying different codes without success.

I have a shapefile with polygons that represents buildings, and some of the vertices have Z values, others have z=0.

What am I doing wrong?

```py
import arcpy

sheet_name = "RPN_2609"
GDB_path = r"D:\Buildings_Height\Case_Study\Part_B\{}.gdb".format(sheet_name)
bldg = GDB_path + "//" + "RPN_2609_BLDG_No_Zero"

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(bldg, ["SHAPE@","OID@"]) as cursor:
  for row in cursor:
      for vertice in row[0]:
          for pnt in vertice:
            try:
                if pnt.Z == 0:
                    pnt.Z = 1
                    cursor.updateRow(row)
            except:
                pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is flawed and not updating the geometry correctly. You need to build a NEW POLYGON and explicitly state it has Z values and insert that back into the FeatureClass. The following code updated my single part test data as expected:

```py
import arcpy

fc = r"C:\Scratch\fGDB_Scratch.gdb\fcTest"

# Get Spatial Reference of dataset
desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
sr = desc.spatialReference

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["SHAPE@"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:

        # Get Geometry
        geom = row[0]

        # Create an empty array object
        arr = arcpy.Array()

        # Read points, if Z is found to be zero reset it to 1
        for part in geom:
            for pnt in part:
                if pnt.Z == 0:
                    pnt.Z = 1.0

                 # Add updated point to Array
                arr.add(pnt)

        # Construct new polygon geometry from array whilst setting spatial reference and indicating it has Z
        newpoly = arcpy.Polygon(arr,sr,True)

        #Update row
        cursor.updateRow([newpoly])
```

Comment: You really ought to use the `SpatialReference` of the source in the `Polygon` constructor, or it may truncate coordinate values to thousandths before the `updateRow` is executed.

Comment: @Vince, very good point, me just being slack, I shall adjust code accordingly!

Comment: thanks! i wrote something similar and it works! :)

Comment: Also the `for pnt in part` needs a test for `if not pnt` to add a `None` and `continue`; see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330288/updating-z-values-with-geometry-of-multipart-and-donut-polygons-with-arcpy