# Updating Z coordinates of points in polygons with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, geometry, cursor

I am trying to update Z values of polygon shape with ArcPy. This script is working without error but increasing the first (0 position vertex) vertex twice. I want to update only once. How can I avoid it?

```
import arcpy

feature = r"D:\acrpy\VV_test\scripts\map1\ZM_KAD_00.shp"  #polygon shape
fields = ["ESRI_OID", "SHAPE@Z"]
whereclause = """{0} = 7""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(feature, fields[0]))
z_increase = 2

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature, fields, whereclause, explode_to_points=True) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print row[1]
        cursor.updateRow([row[0],row[1] + z_increase])
```

[image]

Comment: This is your fourth post on this topic in a week. A link to the Answer that led you to use `explode_to_points` is really required. It seems likely that this is the cause of your difficulty, as well. You should `print` the contents of each Z value before change, to see if the first update altered the closing point as well.

Comment: @Vince, All are different questions with different solutions.

Comment: When you say “found on GIS StackExchange” do you mean a previous Q&A?  If so, please provide a link to it.

Comment: Your debug output is also required for the question to be answerable

Comment: This code is for polygons with multiparts, much different than the code on GIS StackExchange is for polyline. I changed in description..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to insert a new answer rather than editing my previous one as this comes with a new solution that should handle the problematic of updating the geometries of polygons with more than one inner ring as well.

The OP in the comments pointed out that my other answer didn't work for the case "two donuts in one polygon".

Trying myself I was susprised but today I realized this problem has already come up previously in [this other question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14952/arcgis-10-0-arcpy-how-to-create-a-polygon-geometry-from-inner-and-outer-ring-po) where a solution is also provided.

I'll highlight the key part that makes the code you are about to see working with all types of polygons (single-to-multipart, zero-to-many inner rings):

- an `arcpy.Polygon()` is made up of one or more `arcpy.Array()`s
- each `arcpy.Array()` [is constructed with](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/polygon.htm) at least three `arcpy.Point()`s (although they require four per definition, as pointed out by @Vince in the comments; yes, in ArcGIS a "Point" means a "Vertex", quite confusing...)
- a single `arcpy.Polygon()` with more than one `arcpy.Array()` inside is a multipart polygon
- a single `arcpy.Polygon()` with one or more interior rings (alias "donuts"), is NOT a multipart polygon but a singlepart polygon with interior ring(s) (quoting [this](https://community.esri.com/thread/207704-is-a-polygon-with-a-hole-a-multipart-polygon))
- a single part `arcpy.Polygon()` with one or more interior rings is composed by a single `arcpy.Array()` with a `None` value where the inner ring(s) begin(s), for example:

  [[x1, y1],
  [x2, y2],
  [x3, y3],
  [x4, y4],
  None, # start of the inner ring coordinatres
  [x5, y5],
  [x6, y6],
  [x7, y7],
  [x8, y8]]
- Last but not least, `arcpy.cursors` list per each ring (not part, here I mean ring), a starting vertex and an end vertex which are equivalent in terms of coorindates.
- As per the previous assessment, one needs to sikp updating (shifting) either the first or last point otherwise the coincident point is shifted twice.

The modified working code of my previous original answer is shown below:

```
fields = ["OID@", "SHAPE@"]
feature = r"D:\acrpy\VV_test\scripts\map1\ZM_KAD_00.shp"  #polygon shape

fields = ["ESRI_OID", "SHAPE@"]

whereclause = """{0} = 7""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(feature, fields[0]))

z_increase = 2

desc = arcpy.Describe(feature)
sr = desc.spatialReference


with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature, fields, whereclause) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print("Feature {}:".format(row[0]))
        partnum = 0
        # create an array for the updated feature
        arr_feat = arcpy.Array()
        for part in row[1]:
            # create an array for the part
            arr_part = arcpy.Array()
            print("Part {}:".format(partnum))
            i = 0
            for pnt in part:
                if i == 0:
                    print("SKIPPING FIRST VERTEX")
                    arr_part.add(arcpy.Point(pnt.X, pnt.Y, pnt.Z))
                    i += 1
                    continue
                if pnt:
                    print("OLD: {}, {}, {}".format(pnt.X, pnt.Y, pnt.Z))
                    new_z = pnt.Z
                    new_z += z_increase
                    i += 1
                    print("NEW: {}, {}, {}".format(pnt.X, pnt.Y, new_z))
                    arr_part.add(arcpy.Point(pnt.X, pnt.Y, new_z))
                else:
                    print("Interior Ring:")
                    null_point = None
                    arr_part.add(null_point) # MUST DO THIS WHEN INSERTING INTERIOR RING!!!
                    i = 0
            # add part to feature array  
            arr_feat.add(arr_part)
            partnum += 1
        polygon = arcpy.Polygon(arr_feat, sr, True)

        row[1] = polygon
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: It is incorrect to state that polygon rings require three vertices; they require four (and the terminal vertex must be 4-D coincident with the first vertex). The `Polygon` object returned by the cursor has all the required vertices -- the only "extra" is the `None` added between interior rings. The reason the `explode_to_points` doesn't work is linked to the z=z+N task, and the fact that ArcObjects is *helpfully* preventing corruption by updating subsequent and previous vertices in the virtual stream.

Comment: @Vince my assupmtion was based on the example in the [Polygon geometry help](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/polygon.htm), where a part of the polygon is defined as an array of three pairs of x, y coordinates (`[1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 7]`). Anyway, I edited my answer to hopefully be more clear on this point and to include your observation. Thanks.

Comment: The documentation is misleading; ArcObjects makes a number of assumptions to prevent errors, which introduce new errors (e.g., it will "fix" bowties by constructing a pair of triangle parts instead of reporting a self-intersecting shape). If you print the parts, JSON or WKT of the resulting geometry, the required closing point is present. Four points define a ring; the reason the example has three is that the fourth is auto-generated from the first (and only successfully when there is a single ring)

Comment: @umbe1987 Thank you for the good explanation and i tried with the script and its working perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Your case is very interesting to me as it reveals that `explode_to_points=True` is indeed "deconstruct(ing) a feature into its individual points or vertices." (as stated in the [arcpy.da.UpdateCursor help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm)).

**HOWEVER**

as in a Polygon, the first and last vertex of a feature (and all its parts) are coincidents, it seems that updating the geometry of the first vertex automatically updates that of the coincident (last) vertex. Thus, when you reach the last one which has already been shifted, it gets shifted again.

Let's visualyze this:

in ArcMap, I have a simple one feature, one part polygon.
If I start an edit session and see its vertices, I can see it has 4 vertices.

But when I build a cursor and print all its same vertices, I can see there's one more at the end, which is coincident with the first one.

This was also already discussed in [this post](https://bjkronenfeld.wordpress.com/2014/05/15/a-simple-method-to-transform-feature-coordinates/) I just discovered.

[image]

Even if you avoid using the `explode_to_points=True` thing and go through each point in each part explicitly, you'll get the same result unfortunately.

Here you can see the same problem (code adapted from [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/reading-geometries.htm#GUID-9FC74E09-898D-4A5E-9A07-76CD911C2AC6)):

[image]

This seems to me a real problem that should be handled differently by ArcPy.

**SOLUTION**

I guess we're left to avoid touching the first vertex of each part. Something like the same example above combined with [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56813808/1979665) should work:

```
feature = r"D:\acrpy\VV_test\scripts\map1\ZM_KAD_00.shp"  #polygon shape

fields = ["ESRI_OID", "SHAPE@"]

whereclause = """{0} = 7""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(feature, fields[0]))

z_increase = 2

desc = arcpy.Describe(feature)
sr = desc.spatialReference


with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature, fields, whereclause) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print("Feature {}:".format(row[0]))
        partnum = 0
        # create an array for the updated feature
        arr_feat = arcpy.Array()
        for part in row[1]:
            # create an array for the part
            arr_part = arcpy.Array()
            print("Part {}:".format(partnum))
            for i, pnt in enumerate(part):
                if i == 0:
                    arr_part.add(arcpy.Point(pnt.X, pnt.Y, pnt.Z))
                    continue
                if pnt:
                    print("OLD: {}, {}, {}".format(pnt.X, pnt.Y, pnt.Z))
                    new_z = pnt.Z
                    new_z += 2
                    print("NEW: {}, {}, {}".format(pnt.X, pnt.Y, new_z))
                    arr_part.add(arcpy.Point(pnt.X, pnt.Y, new_z))
                else:
                    print("Interior Ring:")
            # add part to feature array  
            arr_feat.add(arr_part)
            partnum += 1
        polygon = arcpy.Polygon(arr_feat, sr, True)

        row[1] = polygon
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

After running this on a single feature shapefile with two parts each with one donut I was able to see the updated Z correctly.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response. i tried your code its working for polygons less than two multiparts/donuts. polygons contain two or more multiparts /donuts got the geometry corrupted.

Comment: you didnt use the whereclause

Comment: Just added whereclause and fields in the cursor

Comment: I just tried it with on feature with two parts each with a donut and it's working (see the picture in my answer with the result).

Comment: I have tried two donuts in one polygon. Geometry got corrupted. I want to add the figure but i dont know how to do it here. I am a bit new here. I am using python 2.

Comment: Don't have time to find out what's gonig on right now, but you're right, if it has two donuts it gets corrupted. Interesting... Will try to investigate on this when I'll have time (next week I guess...). If you find a solution yourself please post it.

Comment: Sure. Have a good day.

Comment: I have an other work around to get the result. The work around is first convert all vertecies to points and add z values to the points and replace them in the polygon. see the link [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330288/updating-z-values-with-geometry-of-multipart-and-donut-polygons-with-arcpy/330293?noredirect=1#comment539355_330293]